# VBA to Hide Worksheets with "Sheet" in Name

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together the code below to hide named worksheets using a Checkbox. The workbook also contains sheets with the generic names like Sheet1, Sheet2, etc and I would like to be able to hide all sheets whose name contains the word "Sheet" from the same Checkbox.

Is this possible?

Thanks

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If CheckBox1 = False Then
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("B10") <> "" Then Sheets(ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value).Visible = False
Else:
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("B10") <> "" Then Sheets(ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value).Visible = True
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want hiding the sheet, or a range, as your code tries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want hiding sheets, please use the next code. It hides all sheets where their name starts with ""Sheet":

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  
  For Each sh In Worksheets
    If left(sh.name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
        sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Hide Worksheet With Pattern

**Reminder**

- At least one of all sheets in a workbook has to be visible.
- There is a third 'visibility' parameter `xlSheetHidden` which is not considered in this solution.
- You can hide multiple worksheets in one go by using an array of worksheet names (fast), but you have to loop through the array to unhide each of them (slow).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    
    Const WorksheetPattern As String = "ShEeT*"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsArr As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If CheckBox1 Then ' Hide
        wsArr = WorksheetNamesToArray(wb, WorksheetPattern)
        wb.Worksheets(wsArr).Visible = xlSheetHidden ' also 0 or False
    Else ' UnHide
        wsArr = WorksheetNamesToArray(wb, WorksheetPattern, xlSheetHidden)
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To UBound(wsArr)
            wb.Worksheets(wsArr(n)).Visible = xlSheetVisible ' also -1 or True
        Next n
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function WorksheetNamesToArray( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetPattern As String, _
    Optional ByVal isVisible As XlSheetVisibility = xlSheetVisible) _
As Variant
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
        Dim wsArr() As String: ReDim wsArr(1 To wsCount)
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim n As Long
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If UCase(ws.Name) Like UCase(WorksheetPattern) Then
                If ws.Visible = isVisible Then
                    n = n + 1
                    wsArr(n) = ws.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
        ReDim Preserve wsArr(1 To n)
        WorksheetNamesToArray = wsArr
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks VBasic, I've learned a lot from this